# How to attach .exe in eclipse for debugging class file

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have an application(.exe) which is calling java code from c++ code using JNI api.
I want to debug java code.
I had tried this on VS2010 but it is not allowing me to go inside java code.
Can anybody help me how to debug this?

Comment: Interesting. How do we really debug C++/Java *together*

Comment: See remote debugging at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html